# Se me Actualiza toda la columna en vez de solo unos campos - MySql java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hola estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con mysql y java a la vez, estoy tratando de realizar una "consulta preparada" de tipo UPDATE, la cual consiste de actualizar el nombre de un producto(el usuario elije el nombre) a partir de un origen(el origen tambien es proporcionado por el usuario), el problema es que en vez de actualizarme solo los campos que contienen el origen dado por el usuario me actualiza TODOS, ejemplo elijo el origen "cl" y tmb me cambia el nombre en los origenes "arg" "china" etc, paso codigo de como creo la consulta preparada

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ACT`(nombre varchar(20), origen varchar(20))
BEGIN UPDATE productos.supermercado SET Nombre=nombre WHERE Origen=origen;
END
```

y asi la ejecuto desde la consola de mysql Workbench

```
Call ACT('jamon', 'cl')
```

hacer esto me pondria jamon en todas las columnas de nombre, aunque su origen no se 'cl'

Comment: WHERE Origen=origen siempre es verdadero, debes de poner WHERE Origen='cl'

Comment: mysql o sql-server?

Comment: es en mysql....

Comment: @JorgeLuis Gracias , ahi entendi , mysql no diferencia entre mayusculas y minusculas, ahora me anda bien xD , gracias

Answer (score 1):

Eso lo hace porque el código no identifica entre el parámetro y el nombre de la columna, por lo que compara la columna contra si misma. Puedes agregar un prefijo a tus parámetros para indicar que lo son y así evitar problemas.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ACT`(pnombre varchar(20), porigen varchar(20))
BEGIN UPDATE productos.supermercado SET Nombre=pnombre WHERE Origen=porigen;
END
```